# Re-use a generated String in Selenium scripts

Tags: java, string, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where I register a user to use 2FA in a website and then use the generated code to generate OTPs in mutiple set of tests.

In my first method, I register to 2fa and use the manual entry to read the code,
My registration page is similar to tis,
[image]

Code,

```js
    public String registerFor2FA() {
        // Register user to use 2FA
        
        // Login to website
    
        // Read secret key
        WebElement secretKey = view.getElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
        String secretKeyReg = secretKey.getText();
        // Enter 2fa code to register
            String code = totp.now(); // generate code
      view.getElement(By.xpath("2-step-setup-code")).click();
      view.getElement(By.xpath("2-step-setup-code")).sendKeys(code);
      view.getElement(By.xpath("done-button")).click();
  }
```

Then I create OTPs using following method,

```js
    public void enterGeneratedOTP() {
        try {
            secretKeyReg = registerFor2FA();
            String secretKey = secretKeyReg;
            byte[] secret = secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            TOTP.Builder builder = new TOTP.Builder(secret);

            builder
                    .withPasswordLength(6)
                    .withAlgorithm(HMACAlgorithm.SHA1) // SHA256 and SHA512 are also supported
                    .withPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

            TOTP totp = builder.build();
            String code = totp.now(); // generate code
      view.getElement(By.xpath("authentication-code")).click;
      view.getElement(By.xpath("authentication-code")).sendKeys(Code);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.err.println("The character encoding is not supported.");
        }
    }
```

And then I use the following testcases to test the login scenarios,

```js
    public void loginUsing2FASuccessfulEmpPortal() {
        // Load employee portal URL
        changeURL(webDriver, empPortalURL);
        // Login to employee portal
    view.getElement(By.xpath("username")).click;
    view.getElement(By.xpath("username")).sendKeys("test");
    view.SendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    view.getElement(By.xpath("password")).sendKeys("test");
    view.getElement(By.xpath("signin")).click;
        // Enter OTP and sign in
        enterGeneratedOTP();
        view.getElement(By.xpath("login")).click;
        sleep(5);
        // Assertion to check whether the user logged in successfully
    }
```

I don't have a problem 2fa runing like this if I only have one script to run. Bu, I have multiple login scenarios which I have to use the same secretKeyReg multiple times. And if I call`enterGeneratedOTP();` in every method, the registration process has to go through 10 times for my 10 scenarios. How do I run the registration process only once and store the `secretKeyReg` to use it to test every login scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store it somewhere, usually in memory, but why not in a file?

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: what do you mean "how do you mean?"  If you were to write the value in a file or properties file or DB, then you could read it later right?  That is assuming that each of your scripts will not be able to read a common static variable or something.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeating the registration process and store the secretKeyReg for multiple login scenarios, you can modify your code to separate the registration step and the OTP generation step. You can create separate class **TwoFactorAuthentication** and pass the wedriver instance.

**Test Class example:**

```
public class Test_Login {
    @Test
    public void loginUsing2FASuccessfulEmpPortal() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        TwoFactorAuthentication tfa = new TwoFactorAuthentication(driver);

        // Load employee portal URL
        driver.get(empPortalURL);

        // Login to employee portal
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("username")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("username")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("password")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("signin")).click();

        // Register for 2FA (if not already registered) and get the secret key
        String secretKey = tfa.registerFor2FA();

        // Enter OTP and sign in
        tfa.enterGeneratedOTP();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("login")).click();

        // Assertion to check whether the user logged in successfully
    }
}
```

you can create an instance of TwoFactorAuthentication by passing the WebDriver instance through the constructor, as shown below:

**TwoFactorAuthentication class:**

```
package com.tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class TwoFactorAuthentication {
    private String secretKeyReg;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public TwoFactorAuthentication(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String registerFor2FA() {
        // Register user to use 2FA
        // Login to website
        // Read secret key
        WebElement secretKey = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
        secretKeyReg = secretKey.getText();

        // Enter 2FA code to register
        String code = generateOTP();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("2-step-setup-code")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("2-step-setup-code")).sendKeys(code);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("done-button")).click();

        return secretKeyReg;
    }

    public void enterGeneratedOTP() {
        String code = generateOTP();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("authentication-code")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("authentication-code")).sendKeys(code);
    }


    public String generateOTP() {
        try {
            // Generate OTP using the stored secret key (secretKeyReg)
            secretKeyReg = registerFor2FA();
            String secretKey = secretKeyReg;
            byte[] secret = secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            TOTP.Builder builder = new TOTP.Builder(secret);
            builder.withPasswordLength(6)
                    .withAlgorithm(HMACAlgorithm.SHA1) // SHA256 and SHA512 are also supported
                    .withPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

            TOTP totp = builder.build();
            String code = totp.now(); // generate code
            return code;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.err.println("The character encoding is not supported.");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now, the TwoFactorAuthentication class will utilize the provided WebDriver instance throughout its methods.